# Angular 8: Frequent Stripe Connection Errors

Tags: node.js, angular, stripe-payments, angular8

Current stack: Stripe V3 integration + Angular 8 with a nodeJS/AWS lambda backend for my SPA.

I've noticed that after upgrading to Angular 8, I frequently lose connection to Stripe which impairs some functionality on various components since I'm making API calls to Stripe to fetch account balance information on component initialization. This is what I see frequently in my browser's console:

[image]

Refreshing the page fixes the issue but this issue is going to provide a bad user experience. I even added the script tag at the bottom of each component file's HTML file to reload Stripe when rendering new components but no luck there. I'm curious to know if anyone else is experiencing the same issue or has ran into this issue and managed to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this could be related to Angular versions. Calling to retrieve this balance is happening in the backend, presumably on one of your lambdas using `stripe-node`.

If you can update your question to provide more details about the request you're making, maybe there will be suggestions to help. But failing that your app should handle these failures and not try to access data on a null response. Instead, maybe should a "retry" UI while you work on the issue with the requests.

One additional thing to try is to [verify reachability](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-reachability) from anywhere you make calls to Stripe's API.